# What shall the recent tab consist of?

Tags: usability, menu, tabs

I have a site which creates activities and perform various functionality in it. It consists of two tabs, current and recent.

Current activity -shows the name of current activity on which user is working at that moment.
[image]

Recent activity -shows the list of names of all remaining activities.

[image]

What shall the recent tab consist of?

1.Display list of all activities User is part of. 
2.Display list of 3 recently opened activities

Comment: I'm slightly confused with your approach as it seems to be that you've decided to have a 'Recent' section without actually knowing what to put in it. That's a bit 'cart before the horse'. Where did the decision to have 'Recent' come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow the example of Goolge Chrome recent tab, it should be **recently used and closed activities**. The recent tab shouldn't show recently used and still open - since that might confuse your users.

There could be a third, fourt and fifth option, as I think you aimed to describe:

3.Remaining activities - as in a ToDo-list

4.All activities - which shows the user every activity from finished to planned.

5.Overdue - showing activities that you need to handle right away.

If you'd like to improve it further you could add a notification number on the activities that is of interest, such as current, overdue and remaining. In this case your link bar could look like

**all | current<sup>(4)</sup> | overdue<sup>(1)</sup> | remaining<sup>(9)</sup> | recent**

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like we're putting the cart before the horse... **instead of asking "what can I put in this empty box I made", ask yourself "what does the user want to accomplish here?"**

Depending on your product, it *might* be "recently viewed" things, or activities the user recently *participated* in... or, maybe it's "owned" things, or "popular" things, or "favorited" things, or "saved" things, or "new" things, or many of these, or something completely different, or none at all.

If the recent tab isn't there to serve a well-understood purpose, consider removing it. **Once you figure out what the user needs to accomplish their goals in this context, make a tab for that instead :)**